# FTP code causes port scan detection

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, ftp

I have a C# Winforms application that iteratively FTPs files from an FTP server, parses the file for information, then returns the information from each file in a loop.  After so many FTP pulls into memory (I'm loading the text files into an array) Mcafee sees my pulls as a port scanning virus and disables to connection.
I thought delaying the thread (Thread.Sleep(int)) might trick my virus scanner from getting this error but the tradeoff is efficiency.  Does anyone know the specs on how fast I can run and not get this port scan error?  I'm not going outside the company firewall (both my laptop and the FTP server and within the firewall).

Comment: Is there no way to whitelist this app on the antivirus?

Comment: Try switching to *passive mode*, so all connections are outgoing.

Comment: "Specs" for your firewall is not a programming question. You better fix your app to behave nicely anyway. But for that you need to show us some of your code. It's particularly not clear if you are using FTP active or passive mode. And hence whether the question is about outgoing or incoming connections.

Comment: Also, why [tag:java] tag?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the warning is that for each transfer of a file a new connection between server and client is opened and in general the port is increased by one each time this happens. From the outside this can look like a port-scan to so called personal firewalls leading to this effect.

There are a couple of possible solutions:

- It seems that you use the so called active mode for the data transfer, i.e. the FTP server is asked to open the data connection to your system. Switch to passive mode where the connections are established by your client, so the sympthom of an incoming port-scan shouldn't exist anymore keeping your personal firewall quiet.
- Whitelist your application or the peers server in your personal firewall preventing it from blocking things.
- Change the setting of your FTP-client (a java library you use in your program or why is there a Java-tag with this question?) to use the same port for the data transfer with active mode. Because it's always the same port, this should keep your personal firewall quiet as well.